# How to correctly reference another object in mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb in my node app and trying to create two entries in two documents. One for an `attendee` and one for `media`.

I want my attendee to reference the media object which sits in the media collection.

Can I simply create an attendee and reference the object:

```
attendee = {
    uuid: 123,
    mediaRef: <mediaID>,
}
```

Or is it best to set a reference object which details the document that is being referenced?

I am not using any ORM of sorts so when I fetch an attendeeID I assume I have to then manually do another query for the related media based on the mediaRef ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think native mongodb has any specific type for references, its just the same type as ID.
Now, for the part about referencing it, you can do that in a single query. What you are looking for is the $lookup operator:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

That beign said, i still recommed using ORM for mongo. ;)